# How to populate value of a column in a pandas df from another df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
dict1 = {'Name': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi' , 'jkl'], 'Group': ['Group1', 'Group2', np.nan, np.nan], 'Class' : ['ClassA', 'ClassB' , np.nan, np.nan]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df1:
    Class   Group Name
0  ClassA  Group1  abc
1  ClassB  Group2  def
2     NaN     NaN  ghi
3     NaN     NaN  jkl
```

Here I want to replace the NaN values by looking up the name and its corresponding group and class values from another df:

```
dict2 = {'Name': ['ghi', 'jkl'], 'Group': ['Group3', 'Group4'], 'Class':['ClassC', 'ClassD']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
df2:
    Class   Group Name
0  ClassC  Group3  ghi
1  ClassD  Group4  jkl
```

So basically I want to replace the df1 values by looking at the mapping in df2. So my df1 should look like:

```
df1:
    Class   Group Name
0  ClassA  Group1  abc
1  ClassB  Group2  def
2  ClassC  Group3  ghi
3  ClassD  Group4  jkl
```

I tried doing df.loc but I am not sure how to make it work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing this:

```
dfNew=df1.merge(df2,on='Name',how='outer',suffixes=('','_y'))
dfNew['Group']=dfNew['Group'].fillna(dfNew['Group_y'])
dfNew['Class']=dfNew['Class'].fillna(dfNew['Class_y'])
dfNew=dfNew.drop(dfNew.filter(like='_').columns,1)

Out[35]: 
  Name   Group   Class
0  abc  Group1  ClassA
1  def  Group2  ClassB
2  ghi  Group3  ClassC
3  jkl  Group4  ClassD
```